# ScrollView not scrollable, due to programmatically inserted data?

Tags: android, scrollview, scrollable

I've seen non-scrollable ScrollView's a few times on stackoverflow.com, but none of the proposed solutions work for me. Ihope someone can help.

I have a ScrollView containing a TableLayout. The TableLayout is empty, but I programmatically insert rows and columns. I am guessing that I need to tell the ScrollView that the TableLayout has changed/updated, and ScrollView needs to recalculate if it needs to enable scrolling.

I tried to invalidate both the ScrollView and the TableLayout, I tried requestLayout(), but nothing seems to do anything. What am I missing?

Here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/maintable" >
        </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is my Java code. Basicly, this code adds a row per player and 25 buttons next to each player. The buttons are there, but they are out of the screen boundaries.

```
    // Get the TableLayout
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    // Go through each item in the array
    for (int player = 0; player < players.length; player++)
    {

        // Create a TableRow and give it an ID
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        tr.setId(100+player);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

        // Create a TextView to add the player name
        TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
        labelTV.setId(200+player);
        labelTV.setText(players[player]);
        //labelTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(labelTV);

        // numShots = 25
        for (int shot = 0; shot < numShots; shot++)
        {
            Button shotButton = new Button(this);
            shotButton.setId((player * 100) + shot);
            shotButton.setText(Integer.toString(shot));
            tr.addView(shotButton);

        }

        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //  Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            //};
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're needing a horizontal scroll?  ScrollView only does vertical scrolling, you'll need to have a look at [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).